# How can I make a tab from a navbar to fill all the vertical space with bootstrap5?

Tags: html, css, navbar, margin, bootstrap-5

I used a bootstrap navbar, I created a hover effect and the problem is that when I click on a tab, the color changes in white but there is still a black margin.

Here is how it looks like:
[how it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXAKk.png)

And here is how I want it to look like:
[how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC9dP.png)

Here is the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Elegant<i class="fa fa-square"></i></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#homepage">HOMEPAGE</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">PAGE</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">FEATURE</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">PRICING</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">BLOG</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.nav-item a {
font-size: 12px;
color: white;
letter-spacing: 2.5px;
padding: 25px !important;
display: block;}


.nav-item a:hover {
background-color: white;
color: black;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the padding of the relevant container to be 0, that is the navbar.

```css
.nav-item a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
  padding: 25px !important;
  display: block;
}

.nav-item a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.navbar {
  --bs-navbar-padding-y: 0;
  padding-top: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Elegant<i class="fa fa-square"></i></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#homepage">HOMEPAGE</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">PAGE</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">FEATURE</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">PRICING</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">BLOG</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```